# How can i get the last integer saved to a textfile and display it i a TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-files

I'm saving random numbers to a textfile between 1-10 and i want to display the last saved number in the textfile in to a TextView so the user can see it.

How can i look for the last saved value in a textfile?
Is there any function for that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use sharedpreferences?

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
// get the current in value or 0 if it's not set
int anInt = preferences.getInt("MY_INT", 0 /* default value */);
// blah
// save the incremented int.
preferences.edit().putInt("MY_INT", anInt++).commit();
```

Comment: Is it possible to save i number and then display it dynamicly in the text view , make it sleep() and then save second number and display it in textvie and so on?

Comment: you could use view.post() to do that on the main thread after you save it... maybe create a new question for that so you can describe the problem more.

Answer (score 0):

i think...

```
EditText randEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

randEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        txtView.setText(randEditText.getText().toString());

    } 

});
```